# structuring data in d3.js to create a matrix

Tags: javascript, dictionary, object, d3.js, data-manipulation

I have this data object:

```
{ferment_id: 2, ferment: "Summer Sausage", organism: "Pc.acidilactici"},
{ferment_id: 3, ferment: "White wine", organism: "S. cerevisiae"},
{ferment_id: 3, ferment: "White wine", organism: "O. oeni"},
{ferment_id: 4, ferment: "Red Wine", organism: "S. cerevisiae"},
{ferment_id: 4, ferment: "Red Wine", organism: "O. oeni"},
{ferment_id: 5, ferment: "Buttermilk", organism: "Lc. lactis "}
```

And I am trying to manipulate it so that I get an array of objects looking like this:

```
{source: "S. cerevisiae", target: "O. oeni", value: 2, ferments: ["White Wine", "Red Wine"]}
```

which would mean that S. cerevisiae & O. oeni both "share" two ferments. I want to make a matrix from this data.

The goal is to make a chord diagram with the organism in a radius, connecting to other organisms if a ferment also shares that organism. I'm not sure how to do the data manipulation part, however.

My first try seems to be on the right track, but not quite there.

```
orgArray = Array.from(d3.group(organisms, d => d.organism, d => d.ferment), ([source, target]) => ({source, target}))
```

Got me this:

```
{source: "S. cerevisiae", target: Map(36)},
{source: "Pc.acidilactici", target: Map(2)},
{source: "O. oeni", target: Map(3)},
{source: "Lc. lactis ", target: Map(1)}
...
```

Comment: In the case where `source` is `O. oeni` and `target` is `S. cervisiae`, what should `value` and `ferments` be ? My guess is exactly the same as if  `source` is `S. cervisiae` and `target` is `O. oeni`... in which case it is not clear how the chord diagram would work ?

Comment: Yea I'm nit sure about the lingo. Probably instead of source and target I should name it something else like org1 and org2. A chord would still work - it just wouldn't be a directed chord diagram.